From Excel to JSON convert an empty string to null using Python
I'm reading an Excel sheet using the Pandas read_excel which gives me a dataframe, then I'm using df.to_json(...) to convert the dataframe into JSON string. However when there are no values in the Excel cell its coming as empty string "" in JSON. How can I ensure that JSON converts empty cells to null values?

Can you provide a [mre]? to_json should give you "null" on empty (=NaN/None) cells: pd.DataFrame({'A': [None, 2], 'B': [1,2]}).to_json() -> '{"A":{"0":null,"1":2.0},"B":{"0":1,"1":2}}'

@samer saleh. What's the version of your pandas module? You can use pip freeze | grep pandas command to check the version.

Suppose your excel file is named test.xlsx. I think the following code is what you're looking for.
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')

# Replace empty strings with None
df.replace("", None, inplace=True)

json_str = df.to_json(orient='records')

print(json_str)

Here's the content of test.xlsx.

And here's the content of json_str.
[{"a":"qq","b":null,"c":"yy"},{"a":"ww","b":null,"c":"rr"},{"a":null,"b":"ee","c":"tt"}]

df.replace("", None, inplace=True) converts the empty cells to null values in json.

Even without df.replace("", None, inplace=True) the output should already be null

You can try: pd.read_json('[{"a":"qq","b":null,"c":"yy"},{"a":"ww","b":null,"c":"rr"},{"a":null,"b":"ee","c":"tt"}]').to_excel('test.xlsx') ; pd.read_excel('test.xlsx').to_json() which gives you the same string without needing replace.

@mozway you're right. I didn't notice that.

Thanks for trying to help. It turns out the reason why I was getting empty string is because of passing(na_filter=False) to the read_excel function. Not sure why is that and maybe I misunderstood what I read about this parameter:
"
Detect missing value markers (empty strings and the value of na_values). In data without any NAs, passing na_filter=False can improve the performance of reading a large file.
"
I'm not sure if the description clear enough though to indicate that it will keep empty string ,since I dont have NAs I thought passing this flag can improve performance.
Maybe someone can elaborate this better to me and I apologize for the false alarm.
Thanks
